Are there any subsets $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $0$ & closed under multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, but not an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Are there any subsets $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $0$ & closed under multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, but not an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$?

This was an exam question at my university but I simply cannot find one.
My progress thus far is as follows:
I understand all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$; it cannot contain $1$ as this would generate $\mathbb{Z}$; and as this is not an ideal, we must have that for any $a,b$ in $I$, $a + b$ must not be in $I$.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$2\mathbb{Z}\cup 3\mathbb{Z}$ would do.

$\Bbb Z \setminus {1,-1}$

Since multiplying by $0$ gives $0$, the "containing $0$" condition is redundant and could be left out if $I$ is nonempty. So, the question could be changed to "Are there any nonempty subsets $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ closed under multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, but not an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$?" without changing the answer.
